# Please support the request for embedding smaller imgur.com images to reduce traffic

Tags: feature-request

This is a follow-up to [this discussion](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/628).

Could you please support [the request on global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107927/132564) to embed smaller versions of imgur.com images and a link to the hi-res version automatically?

Comment: The linked request has been closed as a duplicate on Meta Stack Overflow; however, you can support this request instead: [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph)

Answer (score 2):

While I agree in principle, <strike>I would suggest you ask about this on</strike> the request on Meta Stack Overflow may get more action than asking people to change their behaviors. The method you describe in that question doesn't always work with all images. Perhaps there's a way to get ingur to render smaller images by default?

Comment: Well, I've made a request on global meta. It already contains a handful of comments about how it can be done better.